# Starting debugger : failed ::Codeblocks

Tags: debugging, codeblocks

**Debugger Not Working in codeblocks**

Can someone please point out any possible error in GDB/CDB settings !

**Debugger log:**

```
Active debugger config: GDB/CDB debugger:Default
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target:
     Debug

Adding source dir: C:\Programming\Buddy and Queries\
Adding source dir: C:\Programming\Buddy and Queries\
Adding file: C:\Programming\Buddy and Queries\bin\Debug\Buddy and Queries.exe

Changing directory to: C:/PROGRA~4/BUDDYA~1/.

Set variable:
PATH=.;C:\mingw32\bin;C:\mingw32;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program 
Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
Client;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System
32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management 
Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine 
Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine 
Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine 
Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program 
Files (x86)\Skype\Phone;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common 
Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program 
Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Kartik 
Madaan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

Starting debugger: C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args 
C:/PROGRA~4/BUDDYA~1/bin/Debug/BUDDYA~1.EXE

failed
```

Comment: @Stephen Raunch , sir could you please help me out . Thanks in advance :D

Comment: I do not know the answer to this question.  I merely edited the question help with the formatting.